# Transitive Relations clarification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Given set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

is it okay to say that {(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)} is transitive?

Even though not all the elements of $A$ are not present inside the ordered pairs?

Comment: What's your definition of "transitive"?

Comment: Yes, of course this is transitive.  Nowhere in the definition of transitivity does it require that every element be present in at least one of the pairs.  Be warned as well that transitivity does not require at least three pairs.  The relation $\{(1,2)\}$ is transitive.  Even the relation $\emptyset$ is transitive as well.  Further, be warned that although the definition of transitivity is often phrased with three variables, for example as "*for all $x,y,z$... if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ then $(x,z)\in R$*", these variables do not need to refer to distinct numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this is the reassurance I needed, I wasn't sure because this web calculator: https://relcalculator.freevar.com/ says it is not.

Comment: Don't use "calculators" like this.  They will rot your brain and keep you from thinking for yourself.  They are very frequently incorrect, very frequently poorly coded with inefficient algorithms, and very frequently for profit in some way and do not have your best interest at heart.  They also instill bad habits in terms of thinking there is some specific formula available out there that someone else has already come up with to solve a scenario when your current scenario may be ever so slightly different, but still should be trivial and following from the fundamentals.

Comment: Thank you for your additional advise, I appreciate it!